# How to connect via asyncpg with password? From Python 3.10 all example I see connect without password

Tags: asyncpg

I need example of connect to postgresql using asyncpg from python not only with username, as in documentation on site https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/usage.html, but with password too.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples:
https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/102920/asyncpg.connect

tl;dr

```
return await asyncpg.connect(
    user=DBUSER,
    password=DBPASSWORD,
    database=DBNAME,
    host=DBHOST,
    port=DBPORT,
)
```

parameters are optional, with defaults values, like default host is localhost, default port is 5432, etc.